# saving documents to mongoDB preventing duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to save multiple documents in mongodb using mongoose; and I'm also willing to prevent duplicates. my function looks sth like this:

```
const Stock = require('./models/stock')
let _symbol = 'symb'

const writeToDB = async (dataObj) => {
    try {

        let stock = await Stock.find({symbol : _symbol } , function (err) {
            if(err) return null
        })

    if (!stock) {
        stock = new Stock({
            dataObj
        })
        await stock.save()
        console.log(`${symbol} is successfully saved to database`)
    } else {
        stock = await Stock.updateMany(
            dataObj, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log(`${symbol} successfully added`)
            }
        })
    }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
}
```

but I keep getting timeout error. can someone pls inform me what's wrong.

### update

with a well handled connection approach `findOneAndUpdate()`works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `upsert` option, in `findOneAndUpdate()`. An upsert behaves like a normal findOneAndUpdate() if it finds a document that matches filter. But, if no document matches filter, MongoDB will insert one by combining filter and update as shown below

```
var query = {symbol : _symbol };

try{
   let result = await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(query, dataObj, {upsert: true})
}
catch(err){
  console.log();
}
```

if you have a big collection, for increase speed `findOneAndUpdate()`, you should indexed `symbol` field.

when you use `async` `await`, it's better don't use callback and use `try` `catch`

Comment: thank you for answering but I don't understand this argument : "req.newData" ? and I think there is a tiny mistake in your code : "vanewData= dataObj"  => "var newData = dataObj"

Comment: I keep getting this error when using findOneAndUpdate()  : ```Operation `stocks._findAndModify()` buffering timed out after 10000ms``` is it possible it occurred because of a mistake in mongodb connection?

Comment: do you use this options when you connect ? especially useUnifiedTopology :true `mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best, simply and easy way to prevent duplicate values is use `unique` value in the schema.

So your Stock schema has to have something similar to this:

```js
symbol:{
  type: String, // or whatever
  unique: true
}
```

If you try to insert two object with same value, mongoose will trhow an error like:

```sh
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error dup key: { : "repeatedSymbol" }
```

Also you can check the [documentation](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/unique).